# I set tabs but it did not navigate other tabs in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=create-dynamic-tabs-via-data-attribute

In above link, I found the code for tabs but it's not working.

Comment: Life ain't easy for a boy named Sue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is receiving quite a bit of negative feedback, because you haven't shown any information about your project at all.  Clearly the tutorial works properly, so in order to know why it isn't working for you, it is necessary to evaluate your code and compare it to see what is different, which you haven't given us any ability to do.  Even just the error messages from your console would be better than "it's not working".

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TabController', function () {
        this.tab = 1;

        this.setTab = function (tabId) {
            this.tab = tabId;
        };

        this.isSet = function (tabId) {
            return this.tab === tabId;
        };
    });
})();
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TabController as tab">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(3)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
             <h4>Tab 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
             <h4>Tab 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
             <h4>Tab 3</h4>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Demo Code is working perfectly in FF.

Comment: Can you please check error console from your browser ? You will see error over there. Please check it once. If possible share the link of your application, I can try to find the issue in it.

Comment: Why are you using Jquery Sentax in Angular. Do you need  code for Tab functionality in Angular ? Please take care scope of Angular . If that is not the case then it should work. You are using jquery with Bootstrap. This is very simple functionality which you can easily achieve with Angular.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any help from my end.